# Is it possible to enable mouse right click via Terminal?

Tags: terminal, mouse

Is it possible to enable mouse right click via Terminal?

Comment: Wouldn't that kinda suck? You'd only be able to right click in the top right corner of the screen.

Comment: I mean enable right-click on mouse through Terminal. I used the word "corner" incorrectly. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseButtonMode TwoButton`

To undo: `defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseButtonMode OneButton`

Comment: No need to undo this beautiful thing :P

Comment: I think I love you.

Comment: I think this alone isn't enough. It tells you to ENABLE secondary mouse click, but it doesn't tell you which side of the mouse activates it. I'm still trying to find out how to do it.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat One google search later: https://superuser.com/a/506761/104806

Comment: Thanks, I just gave that a try. No luck. And I'm not sure if you're suggesting I'm too lazy/incompetent to search Google.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me
Restart required

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseButtonMode TwoButton
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse.plist MouseButtonMode TwoButton
```

to revert change TwoButton to OneButton

Answer (score 2):

Depends on mouse you are using too I believe, why not something like this if its the regular Apple mouse?

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist Button2 -int 2
```

Or

```
defaults write /Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist Button2 -int 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If others search for how to perform a right click from a shell script, you can use [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html):

```
MouseTools -x 1000 -y 500;MouseTools -rightClick
```

Comment: This isn't what OP asked. From my understanding, he wan't a command line solution to activating the right click functionality on Mcs

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it with BetterTouchTool.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer. Provide a step-by-step solution or a link to a resource that explains your answer better. This will also help to prevent users from marking your answer down.

Comment: I know this tool. The problem I had was to enable it through command line so that I could put this into an executable bash file to use it in more than one machine easily.