# Enable right click Magic Mouse in Terminal

Tags: terminal, preferences, mouse, contextual-menu

I am trying to enable the right click on a Magic Mouse connected to an iMac running 10.6.8, but due to parental controls, I am unable to gain access to the Mouse System Preferences.

I know you can change other settings through Terminal, is it possible to change it to enable right click as well?

I saw [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118585/is-it-possible-to-enable-mouse-right-click-via-terminal) question, but the command

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseButtonMode TwoButton
```

did not make it work for me. If I do

```
defaults read com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse
```

then is confirms that the TwoButton string was set, but when I right click, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind - logging in and out made it work!

Such an obvious fix.